# Counting and appending filtered related objects in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to count the number of objects with have a foreign key relationship to another object, and which have the flag deleted=0.

`User`'s have a foreignkey relationship to `Accounts` in the models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisation

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    account = models.ForeignKey("Account", null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

In the `views`, for each account I would like to show the number of users who are attached to the account, which also have deleted=0.

Here's the best I could do:

```
@login_required
def accounts(request):
    try:
        accounts = Account.objects.all().filter(deleted=0)
        users = User.objects.all().filter(deleted=0)
    except:
        raise Http404

    account_users = {'a':'a'}
    for account in accounts:
        account_users[account.id] = User.objects.all().filter(deleted=0).filter(account = account.id)

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'accounts':accounts,
    'users':users,
    'account_users':account_users,
    })
    return render_to_response('accounts/accounts.html', variables)
```

In the above, I'm using a dictionary which contains `account.id` => `non-deleted user count`. The problem with this is I can't iterate over the dictionary key in the template...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over dictionary use `items()` method. It returns a iterator over (key, value) pairs.

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
   do_something_with(k,v)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried {% for key,value in account_users.items %}{{ value.count }}{% endfor %} which worked, however I need to iterate within a list like {% for account in accounts %} ... {% endfor %} Do I need to append the count to queryset to do this? Thanks

Comment: Solved. I added an {% if %} conditional which only printed the value if key matched list iterable:     {% for key,value in account_users.items %}
  {% if key = account.id %} 
   {{ value.count }}
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}